# Cancelling navigation on a browser back button doesnt affect the Uri - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am cancelling the navigation by overriding this method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true;
  base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}
```

This works when using `NavigationService.Navigate(...)`

But if the user presses the browser back button, the browser Uri will change, even though the page doesn't change.

How do I prevent the Uri from changing on the browser back button?